# Binding Backbone events when passing silent true to Backbone.History

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

The first state of my Backbone app is rendered from the server. I don't need to trigger the router on page load since I'm bootstrapping my models:

I init the app:

```
    window.App = {
        init:function(root){
            this.root = root;
            this.router = new AppRouter();
            Backbone.history.start({pushState:true, silent:true});
        }
    }
```

route[s]:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes : {
            "" : "index",
            "profile/:id" : "profile",
        },
        profile: function(id){
            var user = new App.Models.User({id: id});
            var view = (new App.Views.Profile({model:user})).render().el

            App.root.empty().append(view)
        }
```

View:

```
    App.Views.Profile = Backbone.View.extend({
        events:{
            "click #toggle" : "toggleTab"
        },
        initialize:function(opts){
            this.model.on('sync', this.render, this);
            this.model.fetch();
        },
        template: Handlebars.templates['profile.hbs'],
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            return this;
        },
        toggleTab:function(){...}
```

I'm passing `silent: true` to Backbone.history so the initial route doesn't get triggered hence the `click` event doesn't get bound. This happens with events that don't trigger the router.
I don't really want to trigger the router on page load and re-render/fetch. `navigate`ing is not an option in this case.

How can I bind events like these in this scenario?

---

### Update / Clarification

For SEO reasons the server renders the html meaning that I already have the html and the data there (i don't really need to `empty()`, re-render, trigger or fetch anything.
I'm using [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) in both the server and the client.
I understand that the problem here is that the "initial page" is not a "Backbone.View" so it doesn't get the event bindings.
I could easily trigger the router and/or replace the content by generating a view but as I already have everything there i'm trying not to do that.
Should I bootstrap only the models and re-render the html?
Is there a *best practice* for this?

Comment: How are you rendering the View if you're not creating it? Like this: http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap ?

Comment: I understand that... my question is: How should I go about it?

Comment: Go about creating what? The view? Just create an instance of the view with the data and append it to the DOM (or use the `id` attribute by setting it in `extend`).

Comment: @Maroshii Could you give more details about how things work?

Comment: @Maroshii Ok so basically your page is already rendered. When the user wants to see a new profile, you create the model and the view. What is the #submit button for? Also, is it wanted that your views don't seem to be inserted in the DOM?

Comment: Exactly. The page is  already rendered. I changed the name of the event function, it was a bit confusing. In this view, i'm not supposed to `navigate` anywhere, just show and hide stuff but I don't get the events whithout triggering the router so i guess that HAS to happen. The views are inserted in the DOM : `App.root.empty().append(view)`. Of course this doesn't trigger on page load and that's the problem.

Comment: I have exactly the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600991/progressive-enhancement-node-js-backbone-js