# Progressive enhancement - Node.js, Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, progressive-enhancement

The node.js server has two roles:

- RESTFul API on routes with prefix /api
- Renders website pages on the others routes (/ /plans /features /terms ...)

For the moment, all my pages render a "Loading page..." combined with the Backbone application that replaces the DOM when the Backbone.router starts.

I would like to build the website pages server-side when an user reaches a page and let Backbone handles the next part of the navigation when the user navigates on the website.

I know how to do it server-side but client-side when a page is loaded with the DOM already built, the Backbone.router loads and then replaces the DOM because it does not know that the view is already preloaded.

How to fix it client-side?

Code:

- The router: http://pastebin.com/aUuXaVm9
- Home view: http://pastebin.com/qS1tHUfq
- Terms view: http://pastebin.com/et1mrbLK

Update: the new code: https://gist.github.com/mathieug/d50c861e63dd647f1c2b
Now I need the runSlider method to be called at the first load.

Comment: Can you provide some view as well?

Comment: Sure, terms view: http://pastebin.com/et1mrbLK

Comment: I just added the home view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start the History, make sure to pass `{silent: true}` as an option to let Backbone know that you've already loaded a complete page.  This will prevent the router from replacing the DOM when the view is already preloaded (the first time).

From the [Backbone.js docs](http://backbonejs.org/#History):

> If the server has already rendered the entire page, and you don't want the initial route to trigger when starting History, pass `silent: true`.

So, your code should look like:

`Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, silent:true});`

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was looking for. But just a question, how do I start the events? For example on my homepage, I've a slider and the init method is in the HomeView. With RequireJS I don't access to any view.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand that question.  When you do `this.homeView = new homeView();`, where `homeView` is your HomeView being loaded by RequireJS, the `initialize` function on `HomeView` will get called.

Comment: Okay, I have a slider in HomeView which is initialized by a method runSlider(). When the HomeView is loaded, I need this method runSlider() to be called. I call it in render but render is not called at the first load (silent:true). But if I also call it in initialize, it will be called on all the views (my router loads all the views in its initialize).

Comment: I change the code, now I create the views in the routes. So, now at the first load, the initialize method is not called anymore. How do I run the slider on the HomeView?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mathieug/d50c861e63dd647f1c2b How do I run the slider on the HomeView at the first load?

Comment: Wherever you're starting your app (i.e. wherever you create an instance of your router, like in an  `app.js` file), you need to create a HomeView object.  So wherever you do your `new MyRouter();`, you also need to do `var home = new homeView();`.  You don't want to call `render()` on it though, because the DOM has already been loaded by the page.  But you do want to call run slider.  So do `home.runSlider();`.

Comment: I'm not necessarily on the home. I'd like the slider to be automatically ran by HomeView:initialize or render.

Comment: If you want the server to render your page (on initial load), then you don't need your Backbone Views to render HTML as well.  But you still need to attach your Backbone views to the DOM elements rendered by the server.  So you need to detect what page is loaded and initialize the appropriate view, making sure to not call render.  How you implement that is up to you, but you should understand the basic idea of it.  One possibility is to remove the `silent:true` option, and store a Boolean value `isFirst`.  That way, the first time your Router matches a route, you'll know to not call render.

Comment: I did that with a Boolean isFirstLoad but I really don't like that tricky workaround. My server renders my pages, it is really simple I just need to load the events of the first view. I think I'm missing something because today all the huge Backbone applications render server-side for the first load and they don't have this problem.